# Google Appengine backend send tasks to frontend?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Google Appengine (Python) app that uses a backend to process longer running jobs. 
I want the backend to communicate things to the frontend. I setup a task worker (and it works fine if I send task from front end). However, tasks sent from teh backend

I found this reference online as an example:

```
taskqueue.add(url='', target=taskqueue.DEFAULT_APP_VERSION)
```

Here's what I have in the backend now

```
taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/sendmessage', params={'message': 'test message'},
                  target=taskqueue.DEFAULT_APP_VERSION)
```

The same line cut / pasted into any front end method handler will fire the task. Any ideas on what I'm missing in the backend process?

Comment: Having the same problem! The Default_app_version doesn't work :(